# can i change starting condition in for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have this in my code

`for (int i=max_position; i<N; ++i) { ... }`

however, inside the loop I am going to update the value of `max_position`, would this affect my for-loop?

Comment: No, `i = max_position` will be executed just *once*

Comment: You cannot, but it seems that what you really want to do is to modify "i" inside the loop, and that is very possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) which is the draft C++14 standard (although every version of C++ and C have had equivalent wording).

> The *for statement*
>
> ```
>  for ( for-init-statement condition(opt); expression(opt)) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>  {
>      for-init-statement
>      while ( condition ) {
>          statement
>          expression ;
>      }
>  }
> ```
>
> except that names declared in the for-init-statement are in the same
>   declarative region as those declared in
>   the condition, and except that a `continue` in *statement* (not enclosed in another iteration statement) will
>   execute *expression* before re-evaluating *condition*. [ Note: Thus the first statement specifies initialization for
>   the loop; the condition (6.4) specifies a test, made before each iteration, such that the loop is exited when
>   the condition becomes false; the expression often specifies incrementing that is done after each iteration.
>   — end note ]

As you can see, once you have initialized `i`, modifying variables used in the expression used to initialize it, will have no effect.  (This is one of the places where the standard is actually very clear.)

Answer (score 2):

No, *initialization* `int i = max_position` will be executed just *once*;
if you want to *affect* the loop, try *reversing* it:

```
 for (int i = N - 1; i >= max_position; --i) {
   ...
 }
```

in this backward loop `i >= max_position` *condition* will be checked at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

no it won't it because you are saying i = max position and the for loop uses the i variable not the max_position variable

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. The first statement in the `for` loop is executed only once.

Once `i` is set, changing the value of the variable that was used to set `i` does not effect `i`.

You are allowed to change the value of `i` explicitly within the `for` loop body though.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not going somehow to affect cycle, since `int i` is initialized once before cycle run with `max_position`, then `max_position` has no effect on cycle anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change the i instead of starting condition, changing the max_position won't effect:

```
for(i = max_position;i<N;i++){
   if(smthHappened)
      i+=3;
}
```